# Any practical method to do annotation on PDF under Linux (64bit) environment?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take notes in PDFs in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/380196/how-to-take-notes-in-pdfs-in-linux)

Adobe's official reader don't support do-annotation under Linux. Evince can't do.

Reading PDF is the last thing on which I can not totally move to a pure Linux environment.

Need tools, thanks!

Comment: What kind of annotation editing are you trying to do?  Create form fields, move or reassign links... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Evince-2.32.0 gentoo amd64.

Open a pdf -> Menu -> Side Panel (check). Probably you're viewing Thumbnails change to Annotations.

Never used that you should do some tests.

Answer (score 2):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) allows annotations, <del>but they aren't stored in the PDF, so they aren't particularly portable.</del> which can be stored within the file if you [compile new versions of Okular with Poppler>0.20](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html).

Mendeley has a linux version that allows pdf annotation. I don't know where annotations are stored.

PDFXchange and Adobe reader (windows version) will both run under Wine, and can be used to annotate.

See:
 - http://ivotron.github.com/2010/11/29/pdf-in-linux.html
 - http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/annotating-pdf-on-linux

Comment: :) It's very helpful, I'd like to try the wine method.

Comment: Now you can actually export annotations to PDFs in Okular: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html
It seems Okular has to be built with Poppler at least version 0.20. It works with Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/).

Comment: ...which does indeed have a Linux port.  Color me pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @Mark Storer: 1st beta version of that was released in January 2009. Latest is v1.1 from August 2009....

Comment: ...but the Linux version does not allow to add annotations.

Comment: "add" and "edit" are not the same thing.  Please be more specific. What EXACTLY do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

[Xournal](https://superuser.com/questions/380196/how-to-take-notes-in-pdfs-in-linux/380237#380237) is one alternative - Have to add some characters to keep the "trivial answer" filter happy.